# What is the path for the environmental variables file in Nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, environment-variables

In **Apache** I store my secret keys for environmental variables in `~/.profile`:
`export HMAC_SECRET=123`

Running the command `printenv | less` in Ubuntu terminal, is giving me the content of the key.

I tried the same in **Nginx** but I cannot view the key.

How to setup reading configuration for `env` in Nginx?

Comment: https://docs.apitools.com/blog/2014/07/02/using-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf.html

Comment: [SOLVED] If you installed Nginx through the Debian or Ubuntu packages, then you can define environment variables in `/etc/default/nginx`. This is a shell script so you must use the export FOO=bar syntax (https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/environment_variables.html).